# Fineuploader 4.4 status spinning but never completes in IE8/9

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader, uploader

Just purchased/downloaded fineuploader version 4.4 and unfortunately it's not working IN IE8 and IE9 the spinning wheel is spinning continuously and never completes

```
    var manualuploader_misc = $('#misc-uploader').fineUploader({

    request: {
        endpoint: '/job/receive'
    },
    multiple: false,
    text: {
        uploadButton: '<div><i class="icon-folder-open icon-white"></i> Select files to upload </div>'
    },
    autoUpload: false,

    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['doc', 'pdf', 'docx','rtf','txt','odt'],
        sizeLimit: 2048000 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
    },
   template: 'qq-template-manual-noedit',
    classes: {
        success: 'alert alert-success',
        fail: 'alert alert-error'
    },

     failedUploadTextDisplay: {
        mode: 'custom',
        maxChars: 100,
        responseProperty: 'error',
        enableTooltip: true
     },

    showMessage: function(message) {

        $('#misc-uploader').append('<div class="alert alert-error">' + message + '</div>');
    }


}).on('complete', function(event, id, name, response) {
        if (response.success) {
            $('#miscUploader').val('1');
             $('#misc-uploader .qq-upload-button').hide();
             $('#misc-uploader .qq-upload-drop-area').hide();
             $('#cv-misc-uploader-element .description').hide();
        }
}).on('submit', function(event, id, name) {
    $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {'misc': 1});
});
```

And also when uploading a file in IE7/8 it appears a popup saying "Do you want to open or save receivee6f442a4.json from websitexxx" .. weird ?!

So what I am doing wrong here? On your website it says it supports IE7+

Uploader can be found this page:
http://www.jobs.lady.co.uk/job/apply/id/509

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing a download dialog in older versions of IE, you are likely not returning the proper Content-Type in your server's response to the upload request.

From the [FAQ](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/faq.html):

> Q: In IE, when my server returns its response to an upload request, I see a “Save As…” dialog box on the client. What am I doing wrong?
>
> A: Your server’s response content-type MUST be “text/plain”. IE does not handle the “application/json” mime-type. You have probably read advice from others that claim “text/html” is also safe. This is not always true. You will run into problems with a content-type of “text/html” if your JSON response contains HTML.

Comment: I understand, but the message appears before a request is being sent to the server ?   I just select file -> press Upload -> it starts to spin .. then the message about jsonfile appears ->then the ajax status wheel is spinning continuously and nothing is uploaded all this in IE8 and IE9  Thanks, any other suggestions ?

Comment: No, the message does not appear before a request is sent to the server.  It appears AFTER the request has been sent, and your server has responded.  I just verified myself.  Your server is indeed returning the wrong Content-Type in the response.  You'll need to fix this.

Comment: json message from the server will be received only if Fineuploader will successfully send any data/status to the server ? something is confusing me here ...

Comment: [Here is a screenshot of your app running in IE9, after the file has been submitted](http://i.imgur.com/b4S2WI3.png).  You can clearly see that your server has received the upload request and responded with a 200 with a Content-Type of "application/json", causing the download dialog.  You need to change this Content-Type in your server's response to "text/plain".

Comment: Ok, i've done that ( not on the live website yet )  and the message about open/save file disappeared Thanks for that ! but now the file wont upload everytime it says 'Upload failed '  ?? any other ideas ? cheers

Comment: This is likely another issue with your server code.  You'll need to open up a new question and provide specifics about your server code, the raw response, and the console log messages.